# How to post html content twitter

Tags: php, html, twitter

is it possible , in twitter ,

my html snippet will or not,

How to post html msg in twitter

Thanks[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/9972/twitterb.gif](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/9972/twitterb.gif)

Comment: Um - Could you write that to be a bit more.. er.. understandable?

Comment: Please format your question better next time.

The question probably goes like that: How do I update twitter status from php?

Comment: We can't really tell you anything about your HTML snippet if you don't show it to us.

Comment: very simple ,

is it possible to add html tags in twitter....

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to send anything up to 140 chars to twitter. There are many classes for php: [probably the best one is here](http://brandontreb.com/the-only-twitter-api-php-class-you-will-ever-need/).

However, if you want to send html and see it "executed" or how to call it, that is not possible since everything is escaped.